# For loop crashes in gnuplot

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I am experiencing an erratic behaviour on a heavy lined gnuplot script.

The script intends to plot borderlines. Filledcurve and line styles are used. Also a mono-parametric family of curves are displayed via

```
plot for [i=1:4] f(x,i) title sprintf("f(x,i) i=%d",i) w l  dt 2
```

I tweeted an example here https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DHbeEgXXkAAV6aS.jpg:large

After this plot I continued introducing Argentina. After a new lines of codes the dashed lines in blue started to behave erratically. Two of them simply vanished.

I started debugging the code and ultimately make use of the **set table** utility outputing the whole plot into a single file.

I found the for-loop was behaving erraticly. The title line showed that the loop variable i was correctly running from start to end values. However the function f(x,i) was not properly fed with the correct value of i.

On the first iteration the value the loop worked fine and the script plotted f(x,1). On the second iteration the function was correctly fed and displayed f(x,2). But hereafter the function was always fed with i=2 despite title string correctly showed the change in i

The resulting plot was

[image: For-loop plot crashing. There should be four lines]

I would really appreciate a hint helping me to find the bug.

---

I will now add a few lines of code. The plot command

```
plot for [i=1:words(europa_cet)] countries u ($1+($2<36?1:0)*15):(mercator($2)) index (word(europa_cet,i)+0) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoCET,\
       for [i=1:words(paises_wet)] countries u ($1+15+dst*word(dst_wet,i)*15):(mercator($2)) index (word(paises_wet,i)+0) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoWET,\
       for [i=1:words(southAm)] countries u ($1+(4+dst*word(dstSouthAm,i))*15):(mercator(abs($2))) index int(word(southAm,i)) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoGET,\
       "magallanes.dat" u (new!=2?$1+dst*15:1/0):(mercator($2)) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoEET,\
   "no_magallanes.dat" u (new!=2?$1:1/0):(mercator($2)) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoEET,\
 for [k=1:5:1] mercator(orto(x,real(b1)+real(k)*real(15.0))) tit  sprintf("orto a %02d signo %d",k,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+1*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",1,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+2*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",2,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+3*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",3,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+4*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",4,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+5*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",5,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+0*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",0,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
```

The `for-loop` (line #6) do not work. Line-by-line calls (lines 7-12) do work.

And the output obtained from `set table`, first lines of each iteration

```
# Curve 43 of 104, 100 points FIRST iteration
# Curve title: "orto a 01 signo 1"
# x y type
-22.5 0.874361°  i
-21.9697 0.887919°  i
-21.4394 0.901287°  i
-20.9091 0.914467°  i

# Curve 44 of 104, 100 points SECOND iter
# Curve title: "orto a 02 signo 1"
# x y type
-22.5 0.407722°  i 
-21.9697 0.426936°  i
-21.4394 0.445968°  i 
-20.9091 0.464814°  i

# Curve 45 of 104, 100 points THIRD iter (REPEATS 2nd)
# Curve title: "orto a 03 signo 1" 
# x y type
-22.5 0.407722°  i
-21.9697 0.426936°  i
-21.4394 0.445968°  i
-20.9091 0.464814°  i

# Curve 46 of 104, 100 points FOURTH iter (repeats 2nd)
# Curve title: "orto a 04 signo 1"
# x y type
-22.5 0.407722°  i
-21.9697 0.426936°  i
-21.4394 0.445968°  i
-20.9091 0.464814°  i

# Curve 47 of 104, 100 points FIFTH iter (repeats 2nd)
# Curve title: "orto a 05 signo 1"
# x y type
-22.5 0.407722°  i
-21.9697 0.426936°  i
-21.4394 0.445968°  i
-20.9091 0.464814°  i
```

Comment: might be related to the fact that `i` is an integer, thus if the function `f` performs any arithmetic operations such as division, etc., the result might be not what is intended - could you try `f(x, real(i))` instead in order to cast `i` explicitly to float?

Comment: Nice. I wish it would have worked. But it failed. I even turned into real all integers inside f. It didn't work either.

Comment: could you post the function in question and/or more complete example? otherwise it is hard to tell what might be wrong...

Comment: Sure. First it is the Mercator proj formula `mercator(lat)=log(tan(180/4.0+lat/2.0))` (angles in degree) and also the terminator line formula `terminator(x,y)=(x-y)<0?atan(cos(x-y)/tan(23.5)):1/0` The function is then `f(x,i)=mercator(terminator(x,b0+i*15))` where `b0` is a real constant. I tried `real(i)` and `15.0` or `real(15)`, no success.

Comment: What is the value of `b0`, and what is the range of your `x` coordinate? Even better: could you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I would assume that for some values of `x`, `i`, and `b0` your function is not defined.

Comment: It is well-defined. Indeed I copy-pasted the function five times and manually wrote the five values of `i`... It worked. Also, as I said in the question, I can see the output of the loop with `set table`. And it is not working.

Comment: I have just edited the question including a few lines of code and the output given by `set table`

Comment: Thank you for updating the question, but it is still not enough to reproduce the effect you are seeing. What is `b1`, and is the function `orto` the same as `terminator` above? What is the "right" output? Could you post a MCVE that would allow us to reproduce the different output of the `for` loop and the individual plot commands?

Comment: Yes, `orto` is the same as `terminator` above. I can not provide a MCVE, at least not now. In fact it all worked fine until I added a few lines, plotting countries and some indeterminate computations. In fact I have a backup of the previous script (the one opperating OK) and I could sort of reverse the changes and, then, be more specific about when the script starts failing.  I find very unlikely someone may reproduce the effect from my wording. I was just wondering  someone may have faced similar behaviour or provide a clue. For the record `b1=27`.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have isolated the problem.

I am pasting again the plot (multi)line. The plot line is run two times one for the left (sunrise) subplot, the second for the right (sunset) subplot in a `multiplot` environment. They differ in the definition of the function `orto` and the value for `b1`.

```
plot "usa.dat" u (usaBool?($1+6*15):1/0):(mercator($2)) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoFET,\
 for [i=1:words(europa_cet)] countries u ($1+($2<36?1:0)*15):(mercator($2)) index (word(europa_cet,i)+0) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoCET,\
       for [i=1:words(paises_wet)] countries u ($1+15+dst*word(dst_wet,i)*15):(mercator($2)) index (word(paises_wet,i)+0) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoWET,\
       for [i=1:words(southAm)] countries u ($1+(4+dst*word(dstSouthAm,i))*15):(mercator(abs($2))) index int(word(southAm,i)) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoGET,\
       "magallanes.dat" u (new!=2?$1+dst*15:1/0):(mercator($2)) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoEET,\
   "no_magallanes.dat" u (new!=2?$1:1/0):(mercator($2)) w filledcurve lc rgb colorFondoEET,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+1*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",1,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+2*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",2,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+3*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",3,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+4*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",4,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+5*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",5,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 mercator(orto(x,b1+0*15)) tit  sprintf("no loop orto a %02d signo %d",0,Signo) w l lc rgb 'blue' dt 2 lw 3,\
 for [i=1:words(europa_cet)] countries u ($1+($2<36?1:0)*15):(mercator($2)) index (word(europa_cet,i)+0) w l lt 1 lc rgb colorLinea,\
       for [i=1:words(paises_wet)] countries u ($1+15*(1+dst*word(dst_wet,i))):(mercator($2)) index (word(paises_wet,i)+0) w l lt 1 lc rgb colorLinea,\
       for [i=1:words(southAm)] countries u ($1+(4+dst*word(dstSouthAm,i))*15):(mercator(abs($2))) index int(word(southAm,i)) w l lt 1 lc rgb colorLinea,\
       "magallanes.dat" u (new!=2?$1+dst*15:1/0):(mercator($2)) w l lt 1 lc rgb colorLinea,\
   "no_magallanes.dat" u (new!=2?$1:1/0):(mercator($2)) w l lt 1 lc rgb colorLinea,\
   "usa.dat" u (usaBool?($1+6*15):1/0):(mercator($2)) w l lt 1 lc rgb 'gray50',\
   for [i=0:2] "ciudadesChile.dat" u ($2-($6-1+((new==0&i==2)?-1:((new==2&i==1)?1:0))-dst*word(dstSouthAm,i+1))*15):(mercator(abs($1))) index i w p pt 7 lc 1 ps 1.5,\
   "ciudadesUsa.dat" u (usaBool?($2+6*15):1/0):(mercator(abs($1))) w p pt 7 lc rgb 'blue' ps 1.5,\
 for [k=1:5:1] mercator(orto(x,real(b1)+real(k)*real(15.0))) tit  sprintf("orto a %02d signo %d",k,Signo) w l lc rgb 'green' dt 2 lw 10,\
 for [i=0:2] "ciudadesChile.dat" u ($2-($6-1+((new==0&i==2)?-1:((new==2&i==1)?1:0))-dst*real(word(dstSouthAm,i+1)+0))*15-$4*.5):(mercator(abs($1+$5*1.1))):(stringcolumn($3)) index i w labels font "Arial-Bold,10" tc rgb word(corporativa,1),\
   "ciudadesUsa.dat" u (usaBool?($2+6*15-$4*.5):1/0):(mercator(abs($1+$5*1.1))):3 w labels font "Arial-Bold,10" tc rgb 'blue',\
 for [i=1:words(Coastlines)] coastline u 1:(mercator($2)) index (word(Coastlines,i)+0) w  l lt 1 lc rgb 'gray50',\
```

Problem is with the 3rd line from bottom, the one starting with `for [i=0:2]`.

If this line is removed; the loop `for [k=1:5:1]` operates ok.

If `for [k=1:5:1]` is placed after 3rd  line from bottom, the script operates ok.

If `for [k=1:5:1]` is placed before 3rd line from bottom, the loop does not operate fine.

[image: Image produced in failure mode][image: Image OK]

The `for [i=0:2]` prints names of Chilean and Argentinean cities. Column `$1` is latitude, `$2` is longitude. They are displaced from center throu `$4` and `$5`. The variable `i` through `index` controls the country: `Argentina=0` `Chile=1` `RegionMagallanes (Chile)=2`. The variable `new` controls time zone in Chile `new=0` is prior to 2015; `new=1` is current status, `new=2` refers to 2015. Column `$6`refers to a reference time zone (-3 Argentina and Magallanes, -4  Chile).

The script also controls winter (`dst=0`) or summer (`dst=1`) condition.

I have tried and remove pieces (monomials) of the `for [i=0:2]` line one by one. No success. Even I edited the `ciudadesChile.dat` file and changed a tab separating `$1` and `$2` to a space. No success.

Comment: That sounds quite odd. Which version of gnuplot are you using? You might want to contact the experts on one of the [gnuplot mailing lists](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/mailman/?source=navbar).

Comment: Yeah quite odd. That's why I posted. I'll try a mailing-list. I am not used to it, though.